# Joint Kolmogorov complexity of elegant programs

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

If $a$ and $b$ are different elegant programs (minimal program for some output), is their joint Kolmogorov complexity the sum of their individual complexities, i.e. $K(a,b) = K(a) + K(b)$?

Comment: What is an *elegant program*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus A Turing machine $M$ is elegant if $|\langle M\rangle|\leq|\langle M'\rangle|$ for every other Turing machine $M'$ that computes the same function.

Comment: I'd expect the answer to be "no". Most strings are incompressible, so it should be possible to find two very similar strings for which the shortest program is just `print "The string"`. But, now, the shortest program that prints both strings is essentially `print "The string" twice except make these small changes the second time`, giving $K(a,b) = K(a) + \text{a bit} \ll K(a)+K(b)\approx 2K(a)$. In general, $K(a,b)=K(a)+K(b|a)+O(\log K(a,b))$.