# Is Kolmogorov-random nonsensical for small numbers?

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

The [Wikipedia definition of Kolmogorov-random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Kolmogorov_randomness) defines a string (usually of bits) as being random if and only if it is shorter than any computer program that can produce that string.

Aren't nearly<sup>1</sup> all strings shorter than a certain length<sup>2</sup> going to be Kolmogorov-random?

1. If a random Turing machine is chosen, then programs that output short strings will almost always be longer than the strings. If the programming language used for measurement is optimized for outputting a short string, then only the complexity of a subset of short strings can be made lower than their length. For example, if a Turing complete language defines $0$ as an operation that outputs `0` and halts, the program for outputting `1` and halting is forced to be longer than the length of its output.
2. The exact length below which this occurs will depend on the programming language chosen. [The length is 41 bits using 5 state, 2 symbol Turing machines.](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0096223#article1.body1.sec4.sec2.sec8.p5)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "nonsensical".

Comment: I mean that, while the definition is self-consistent, the small numbers that are Kolmogorov-random don't resemble any other reasonable definition of random.

Comment: Ah, but what is a "reasonable definition" of randomnes? There are many definitions, but kolmogorov randomness, to me, is the most useful. What do the other definitions say about the randomness of small numbers?

Comment: Something like "no betting strategy can make money betting on a random sequence". A sequence of all `0` is easy to bet on, yet sequences shorter than ~33 bits are all Kolmgorov-random.

Comment: Without even using alternative definitions of randomness, it seems problematic that **all** short substrings of non-Kolmogorov-random strings are Kolmogorov-random.

Answer (score 5):

> Is Kolmogorov-random nonsensical for small numbers?

Although one *could* pick a *specific* [description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Definition) to make Kolmogorov complexity into

a function from ​ {0,1}<sup>*</sup> ​ to ​ {0,1,2,3,...} , ​ most people don't pick as described ​ ( [0](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75110/12859) , [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75025/12859) , [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74462/12859) , [3](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/36834/6973) ) ,

so basically:

Kolmogorov complexity is [only defined up to an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Invariance_theorem) additive [O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)(1), so one

needs an infinite set of strings to make sense of Kolmogorov randomness.

In particular, **yes**, Kolmogorov-randomness is nonsensical for small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that K-complexity, at least as an indication of randomness, becomes much more meaningful above the "water line" of string size N where you start having K(x) < N/10, although I'm not sure where that water line should sit.  You might look into a concept called algorithmic specified complexity, which is a kind of randomness deficiency like computational depth.  For an appropriate probability measure, a short but "random" K-complexity might still be a meaningful idea but not necessarily as randomness *per se*.